# How do I make the menu collapse to mobile earlier in Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to be able to manipulate the breakpoint at which the menu collapses to it's mobile version with the 3 stacked horizontal bars.

[image]

Comment: please give information in details.

Comment: So, you somehow overlooked the "[Changing the collapsed mobile navbar breakpoint](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)" box in the official docs?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating your own customized version of Bootstrap. The easiest way to do this is to go to http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ and to set the `@grid-float-breakpoint` variable.

This will keep the breakpoints for mobile, tablet & desktop at their regular values and only change the point at which the `.navbar` collapses.

Answer (score 0):

You can customise bootstrap with your own required break points.

Go [here](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) and in the ‘Media queries breakpoints’ section and adjust the @screen-sm (mobile), @screen-md & @screen-lg parameters as required ...then generate and then replace your custom bootstrap over the existing bootstrap assets.